# Get id element of an <a> tag

Tags: javascript

I'm parsing XML and putting it in a simple table like this:

```
function showData(message) {
    var str = "<table border=1 class='editable'>";
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        str += "<tr>" + "<td>" + message[i].id + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + message[i].name + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + message[i].url + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + message[i].desc + "</td>" + 
                       "<td>" + "<a href='javascript:deleteRequest();' id=message[i].id>delete</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    }
    str += "</table>";
    return str;
}
```

I have an  tag in the last column of my table and I'm trying to set the id of the  tag, or be able to get it from my deleteRequest method so I can delete that entry in the table.

1) I'm not sure if I'm setting the id correctly for the  tag.

2) I'm not sure how to get the id in my deleteRequest method for the selected  tag, like a sender in iOS, or maybe to pass the id in as an argument to deleteRequest().  I'm not sure which method is better.  I tried to do a simple alert(arguments[0]) to see what gets passed in this case, and I get undefined.  So I'm kind of lost what to do as I'm just learning Javascript.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this for the line with the link in it:

```
"<td>" + "<a href='javascript:deleteRequest(this);' id='" + message[i].id + "'>delete</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";

// OR, without the extra + operations:
"<td><a href='javascript:deleteRequest(this);' id='" + message[i].id + "'>delete</a></td></tr>";
```

You weren't concatenating the *value* from `message[i].id` into the string you are producing, you were including the string "message[i].id". (Note that that line ends up looking similar to the four lines of code before it.)

If you pass `this` as a parameter to your function, like `deleteRequest(this)` as shown above you can do this:

```
function deleteRequest(el) {
   // el is the <a> that was clicked
   alert(el.id);    // displays the id from the row that was clicked
}
```

(Obviously the `alert(el.id)` is just an example of how to access the `id` property, you'll do whatever you want with it at that point.)

Note about terminology: Your question title was "Get id element of an  tag" - `id` is an *attribute*, the link is an anchor *element* (or "a" *element*), and in your html markup the anchor element is defined with an `<a>` *tag*. (Similarly, "href" is an *attribute*.)

EDIT: I just noticed you have your JS embedded within the `href` attribute. I'm not sure if that will work properly with the `this` keyword, but in any case a better way to do it is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="deleteRequest(this); return false;">
```

Or, within your code:

```
"<td><a href='#' onclick='javascript:deleteRequest(this);return false;' id='" + message[i].id + "'>delete</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: any advice on how to troubleshoot the problem some more?  I understood your answer, but I get undefined on alert(el.id).  Typeof is equal to object.

Comment: See my edit. I think calling your function from within the `href` attribute was not setting `this` properly (so it was probably equal to `window` instead of the clicked anchor and `window.id` would be undefined though `typeof window` is "object"). `this` will be set correctly if you use `onclick` - the extra `return false;` on the end is to cancel the default action for a click, which is to navigate to the specified URL - specifying "#" means it wouldn't really go anywhere anyway, but without `return false` it might scroll back to the top of the page).

Comment: great!  Thanks for the thorough explanation and updated solution!